# Мой ToolBar находится слишком высоко из-за чего это выглядит уродливо и экран снизу обрезается, как это исправить?

Tags: java, android, design, toolbar

Вот мой экран с toolbar'ом.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Include your Toolbar -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- Embed your fragment in a Layout View-->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.Activities.MenuActivity"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Как он выглядит на телефоне:[image]
Можно увидеть, что toolbar слишком высоко.
Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Activities.MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        tools:ignore="InnerclassSeparator" />
    <activity
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

MenuActivity.class

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Drawer(toolbar,MenuActivity.this,MenuActivity.this);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Аппараты");
    }
```

void Drawer:

```
public void  Drawer(Toolbar toolbar, Context context, android.app.Activity activity){


    DatabaseReference rootRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference uidRef2 = rootRef2.child("users").child(getUid());
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener2 = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String email = dataSnapshot.child("account").getValue(String.class);
            String Avatar = dataSnapshot.child("Avatar").getValue(String.class);
            Long coinsAmount = dataSnapshot.child("coinsAmount").getValue(Long.class);

            String coinsView = "Баланс: " + coinsAmount;




                if (Avatar.equals("1")) {
                    avatar = (R.drawable.a1);
                }
                if (Avatar.equals("2")) {
                    avatar = (R.drawable.a2);
                }


            IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem()
                    .withName(email)
                    .withEmail(coinsView)
                    .withIcon(avatar);

            AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                    .withActivity(activity)
                    .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.account_header_background)
                    .addProfiles(
                            profile
                    )
                    .build();


               result = new DrawerBuilder()
                    .withActivity(activity)
                    .withToolbar(toolbar)
                    .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Устройства")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.device)
                                    .withIdentifier(1)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Сканер")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.scaner)
                                    .withIdentifier(2)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Магазины")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.shop)
                                    .withIdentifier(3)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Купоны")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.coupons)
                                    .withIdentifier(4)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Архив Купонов")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.oldcoupons)
                                    .withIdentifier(5)
                    )
                    .withOnDrawerItemClickListener((view, i, iDrawerItem) -> {
                        if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1 && !Activity.equals("Menu")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2 && !Activity.equals("Scaner")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DecoderActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 3 && !Activity.equals("Shop")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,ShopActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 4 && !Activity.equals("oldCoupons")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,oldCouponsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        return false;
                    })
                    .build();

            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            Objects.requireNonNull(result.getActionBarDrawerToggle()).setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    };
    uidRef2.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener2);




}
```

Как это исправить и сделать как у всех?

Comment: Не понял, в чем уродство? Тонкий тулбар? Сделай на пол экрана.. Глянь тему про стили или кастомизацию тулбаров.

Comment: Попробуйте вот это в корневой элемент разметки добавить: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Если в теме не нужен action bar, то и используйте Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar, Тогда не понадобятся window атрибуты в стиле

Comment: @Игорь эммм... Вы не видите того что он сразу под временем?

Comment: @Игорь и то что экран снизу обрезан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо вот это в корневой элемент разметки добавить:

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: только есть одно НО почему то это работает через раз. То есть когда я только запускаю активити её тулбар все так же находится высоко, но если её перезапустить все ок

Comment: Извините, что не сразу отписал

Comment: Наверное это от того, что вы не сразу Drawer настравиаете, а только по ответу с Firebase. По идее вам надо Drawer сразу настроить и уже потом менять его, когда получите данные юзера.

Comment: вы случайно не знаете как это реализовать? а то я все надумать не могу

Comment: @georgiy110802, настройте Drawer в OnCreate активити. Данные юзера оставьте пустыми. В колбэке с данными получите ссылку на Drawer (хз как, надо доку либы читать. Скорее всего просто через findViewById()) и замените пустые данные юезра на полученные.